# Export Listview items to excel, getting subitems not a member of listviewItem error

Tags: vb.net, excel, listview

I am currently populating a listview with data from a database based on text that a user enters to a search textbox.

```
<ListView x:Name="listSearchServer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="282" Margin="20,50,33,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

So when I run my SQL and get the data that i need, I add these items to the listview

```
While reader.Read()

                countvalues = countvalues + 1

                'Populate the SearchServers listview with result from query

                Dim share = reader("ShareName")
                listSearchServer.Items.Add(share)

            End While
```

Now I have added a button to export the results to excel and I have used the following code that is bringing back an error- "subitems not a member of listviewitems"

```
Private Sub cmdExportServer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExportServer.Click


    Dim xls As New Excel.Application
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

    xls.Workbooks.Add()
    book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
    sheet = book.ActiveSheet

    Dim row As Integer = 1
    Dim col As Integer = 1

    For Each item As ListViewItem In listSearchServer.Items

        For i As Integer = 0 To item.SubItems.Count - 1
            sheet.Cells(row, col) = item.SubItems(i).Text
            col = col + 1
        Next
        row += 1
        col = 1
    Next

    xls.Visible = True

    sheet = book.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Is this because I don't have sub items? does anyone know how I could export the data to excel.

**EDIT**

```
Dim row As Integer = 1

    For Each item As String In listSearchServer.Items

        sheet.Cells(row, 1) = item
        row = row + 1
    Next
```

For this example i did not actually need to move across columns, and the "For Each item As ListViewItem" was changed to "as String" and then for each row I assigned the item in the listview to the excel column row and incremented each time which worked fine.

Thanks to @jelly for the help

Comment: is this line causing you the error "sheet.Cells(row, col) = item.SubItems(i).Text"?

Comment: yeah, error saying, "SubItems not a member of ListItemsView

Comment: ...and the line above that also makes reference to "SubItems"

Comment: yeah, sorry, both references of items.SubItems causing an error

Comment: trying to reproduce the error in my part hold on

Comment: no problem DC, i mean AC ;)

Comment: In the future, could you please make an effort to focus your questions on the specific problem? If the error has to do with ListView items, what is the point of including all the code which you are executing afterwards? Please, help us to quickly help you :)

Comment: @varocarbas hes trying to show his efforts ;) give the guy some slack

Comment: No worries, just wanted to show how the data was being populated to the listview

Comment: @Jelly I am helping him understand how to maximise the efforts. Because spending more time on writing the question and getting downvotes/not getting a quick answer when it might easily be corrected...

Comment: the for loop code compiles fine on my end is there anything else in your that named SubItems?

Comment: No, I have no reference to SubItems in my code, I've looked online and seems as if most code uses subitems to populate the excel sheet, I'm thinking it's because I am reading the data from the SQL result and populating the Listview without specifically stating any sub items. Would this lead to a problem?

Comment: yup you solved it kudos to you big guy

Comment: use   item.SubItems.AddRange to your data to the subitems

Comment: by any chance do you know what i would use instead of "items.Subitems.Count". Basically I need the thing to loop through the listview and the item to each cell in excel

Comment: were exactly do i add that ?

Comment: after you add the item from the sql, add the subitems of that item?

Comment: you do a foreach loop instead of a for loop?

Comment: @Jelly see edit for how i sorted this, I get what you mean in your fix as this would allow me to be able to move across columns and loop through the list, but in this case i only needed it for one column and a number of rows, thanks for your time !

Comment: For this example i did not actually need to move across columns, and the "For Each item As ListViewItem" was changed to "as String" and then for each row I assigned the item in the listview to the excel column row and incremented each time which worked fine.